# How do I input an specific cell for every i in a loop on google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

One of my projects is making a sales spreadsheet.

The sales spreadsheet contains the names of the products and their prices are in the documentation, the challenge is getting the prices to automatically show up on the cell right next to the product name in the spreadsheet.

Here's what I did:

```
function Autoprice() {
  var sales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales')
  var salesrow = sales.getRange('D2:D'+sales.getLastRow())
  var productnames = salesrow.getValues()
  size = productnames.length+1
  for (var i = 0; i< size; i++){
    if (productnames[i+1]=='Diary')
    {
      sales.getRange('F'+i).setValue(31.90)
    }
```

And I just input all the prices manually.
The thing is, google script does not read the `sales.getRange('F'+1)` as I thought it would, and I can't find the correct way to read that for every item in 'DI' cell, i want to put a price on 'FI' cell.

Comment: If you can please share the file you use, so we can replicate. Remove sensitive data if there's any.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please bear in mind that sharing a spreadsheet will expose your email address. By the other hand, questions should be self-constained, so instead of adding a link to a spreadsheet, briefly describe your spreadsheet structure and add some sample data and the corresponding expected results.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! This is what I attempted to do with the code i posted. The entire spreadsheet is sensitive information so I can't share it, that code is pretty much all I got. If it helps, my thinking with that code was "I made var productnames a list with all the products on the sheet, and the for part is supposed to read it, and add the price to cell "D i ", i being the product's name placement on the list. But I don't know how to make it reat "D i" as I intended.

Comment: Please bear in mind that all the relevant details should be added directly into the question body. P.S. `DI` and `FI` looks to be wrong references.

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73965155/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this script, I modified a couple of lines in the sample you shared and added comments next to it to explain.

```js
function Autoprice() {
  var sales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales')
  var salesrow = sales.getRange('D2:D'+sales.getLastRow())
  var productnames = salesrow.getValues()
  size = productnames.length+1
  for (var i = 0; i< size; i++){
    if (productnames[i]=='Diary') //If you do productnames[i+1], you're not starting from the beginning of the range, basically you're starting from D3 instead of D2
    {
      sales.getRange(i+2,6).setValue(31.90) //You can try getRange(row, column) instead
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop through a 2-dimensionall array (not technically... but each element is a single array).

So to see D2's value you would need `productnames[0][0]`

However, you can easily fix this using the flat() function. Modify one line of code below:

```
var productnames = salesrow.getValues().flat();
```

Also consider learning to use the debugger. If you step through your code, this is easy to see.